# Top command - what do the "slash number" next to each process name mean?

Tags: command-line, top

I couldn't find what is the meaning of the `/N` below in the `top` command

```
rcuos/1

migration/1

kworder/1:0H
```

What do those numbers mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the process. The `/…` is part of the process name, as can be seen from `pgrep` output:

```
$ pgrep kworker -a | head
5 kworker/0:0H
16 kworker/1:0H
21 kworker/2:0H
26 kworker/3:0H
31 kworker/4:0H
36 kworker/5:0H
41 kworker/6:0H
46 kworker/7:0H
165 kworker/0:1H
```

For `kworker` processes, the answer is in [this Unix & Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152865/70524):

> According to [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt), the syntax is `kworker/%u:%d%s (cpu, id,
>   priority)`. The `u` designates a special CPU, the unbound cpu, meaning
>   that the kthread is currently unbound.
>
> The workqueue workers which have negative nice value have 'H'
>   postfixed to their names. ([source](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/3/19/661))